# Scotty + Html -> how to intertwine them?

Tags: html, haskell, scotty

How can I work with html pages, **including** html templates, in Scotty? But not via Blaze because I don't like describing its structure in haskell code. It think I should heist, but how exactly to intertwine it with Scotty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Heist.renderTemplate` to turn a template into `Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Builder` (that's not blaze-html, I assume that's okay) and then set that via `Web.Scotty.raw`. For example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Heist
import Heist.Interpreted

import Web.Scotty (scotty, get, raw, setHeader)

import Control.Monad.Trans.Either (runEitherT)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder (toByteString)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as DBL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as DT

import Text.XmlHtml

main = scotty 3000 $
    get "/" $ do
        -- normally you would probably load your templates from a file,
        -- but to keep the example small
        (Right heist) <- liftIO $ runEitherT $ initHeist emptyHeistConfig
        let heist' = addTemplate "foo" [TextNode "Hello world!"] Nothing heist

        (Just (builder, mime)) <- renderTemplate heist' "foo"

        setHeader "Content-Type" (DT.decodeUtf8 $ DBL.fromStrict mime)
        raw $ DBL.fromStrict $ toByteString builder
```

Comment: so theoretically I can use Heist exactly the same way in Snap?

Comment: @Mario I have no experience with Snap, but if you can hand it a ByteString in response to a request, sure.